# Improve the comments interface for new contributors (and reduce work for curators): how to "ping"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, welcoming

I spent some time in the "First Questions" queue the other day, as well as fielding a number of posts from new users in my tags during the last week...

And I found myself regularly telling the newbies that in order to ensure a person they were replying to in comments gets notified, they need to precede the display name with `@`.

This is (as far as I know) something very specific to Stack Overflow, so we can't expect those new to the site to know this. It's also very important for helping questions get edited into an answerable state. People respond, and get no interaction back from those who've requested more information and would (supposedly) be able to answer based on the request. This may not be as big an issue in high-traffic tags, but it certainly is in low-traffic ones.

I propose that "New Contributors" are automatically shown a "hint" about how to "ping" others when writing a comment.

(And the prompt should probably have a "Don't show this again" checkbox when the newbie feels they've learned this aspect of the site.)

(See also my [other request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389225/improve-comment-experience-for-new-contributors-tip-about-editing-information-i) for helping newbies to learn about the edit link.)

Comment: I don't disagree with making the UI easier to use, but the `@` syntax is not at all unique to SO. It's used at tons of social media and communication platforms, to the point where [even Merrian Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/dont-at-me-symbol-twitter-verb) has been writing articles about it. But I guess that means it provides even more value to teach people about it if it's a new concept to them since they might benefit from it many other places.

Comment: OK, @ivarni, thanks for that :-) I know **I** needed to learn it here. I use *no* social media whatsoever, which explains why it would be new to me. I am familiar with it from e-mail, but never would have associated that knowledge with needing it to notify in a "forum". Previously, I only ever communicated in forums and newsgroups, where there was either no notification, or notification of a reply in a "thread".

Comment: So basically automatically expand the box that you get when you click the "help" link next to the comment input box.

Comment: @Gimby Ummmm.... This is the first time I've ever clicked that link. Which maybe tells us how helpful it really is. No, actually I was thinking of something more "in your face", the way the "New Contributor" signs are. On reading that help link, I can see that "ping" is mentioned there, already -but obviously lots of people aren't seeing it.

Comment: After you click it it's pretty hard to ignore isn't it? Nice big yellow box. I am implying you don't need to click anything, the box should be just there. Until you tell it to go away and then it becomes the help link.

Comment: Havee you seen [this proposed UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99261/tell-the-user-who-will-be-notified-of-a-comment) that was never really implemented despite being marked status-completed.

Comment: @RobertLongson No, I'd not seen that. Not sure how relevant/helpful it would be for the scenario that prompted me to make a suggestion. If a newbie saw who would be notified that still wouldn^t tell them how to notify someone else. The cases I've been seeing *en masse* recently have been OP-newbies replying to multiple comments requesting more information - people trying to save questions that are too broad, need a mcve or are unclear. A year or so ago, we'd have just VTC and moved on. Now we're trying to help "everyone": it's time-consuming, monotonous and at some point you just give up.

Comment: we could extend the proposed text to explain how.

Comment: @Gimby Hard to ignore, but also hard to process as it's providing "too much" information IMO. Just speaking from the way my brain works... I'm concentrating on responding to requests for more information - that's where my thoughts are. I'm not going to break that train of thought to process *all* the information in that yellow box when I want to be typing. If the first three or four words aren't relevant to what I'm doing, I'll ignore the rest as my assumption will be it's all about the same topic. Other minds might work differently...

Comment: @RobertLongson You mean implement the proposal, not change existing text? Because I don't recall having ever seen anything like this... But sure. I'm not "married" to my suggestion of how it's done, just that I feel something is needed that will help both newbies and curators.

Comment: Frankly, I would do away with pinging users completely. Deemphasizing comment tooling is a good thing. Notifications should be all about posts (new answers, edit on your posts, comments to your own posts, etc).

Comment: @yivi see my comment to Raedwalds answer...

Comment: It's not very specific to SO. Twitter uses it.

Comment: @OrangeDog **1** If you visit someone's profile on Twitter, there are at least 5-7 `@` lying here and there. No such hints on SE. **2** There's no reason to believe that all SE users know how twitter works. you need exception? Here I am. Never used Twitter.

Answer (score 4):

Current placeholder in the comment box is this:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

It can be changed to something similar to

> Use comments to ask for clarification or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”. Use @ to notify people if there are multiple users in the thread or if its essential to get the attention of a specific user.

Comment: [Changing placeholder of comment box for adding @ pinging info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332638/561132) on main meta and some official response in [in movies SE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/conversation/comment-box-fixing-response-couldnt-select-my-message-it-being-inline) by Catija

Answer (score -2):

No thank you.

If someone posted a comment on a new user's question, the comment should have been explaining why the question is lacking information or is off topic. The correct response by the user should be to edit or delete their question, not to initiate a conversation. But if the new user posted a bad question, they almost certainly didn't read the advice presented to them about how to ask questions, and probably don't understand what comments are for and what they are not for. Making it *easy* to do what we don't want them to do will make things worse.

Making the feature *slightly* obscure is a good thing. Only those with experience of the site, or who have bothered to examine related questions before posting, then know how to use the feature, and so are more likely to use it properly.

Comment: In the cases I've been working with the OP is trying to reply to the person who requested more information to tell them they've provided it, not carry on a conversation. If they can't do that, then the person cannot come back and try to answer the question. In a high-traffic tag this may not be such an issue - lots of people are looking at the questions. In a low traffic tag there may be only two or three people who can provide quality answers. If they don't get notified and don't go back and look, no one answers...

Comment: ...And the OP feels the site is "unfriendly" because no one comes back after they've shown good will and responded. I had a case like that a few weeks ago. Not a newbie programmer or a student, just not familiar with the site and very confused because no one was coming back after he provided more information. Once he understood about "pinging" and that this was the communication disconnect, everything was fine.