# Improve comment experience for new contributors: tip about editing information into the question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, welcoming

Similar to my experience [telling users to use `@` to ping](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389224/improve-comments-interface-for-new-contributors-and-reduce-work-for-curators), I also often find myself explaining how to use the [edit] link to include additional information in the question, itself, instead of in a comment.

I think it might help to show "New Contributors" a message with an EDIT link in it when they start to write a comment with a prompt that says, if they're adding more information whether they wouldn't want to add it directly to the question.

If they turn that down, and then begin to write a comment, anyway, display the "ping" hint.

If they add to the question, automatically generate a comment that "pings" the users who have posted comments - maybe a list from which the newbie can choose who to "ping".

(And the prompt should probably have a "Don't show this again" checkbox when the newbie feels they've learned this aspect of the site.)

Comment: Perhaps the tip should automatically be disabled for everyone with the editor badge.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking it should stop as soon as the "New Contributor" mention goes away. That's why I explicitly mention "New Contributor" in the suggestion @RobertLongson I don't think anyone else should need to see it... although I'm sure some non-frequent visitors with low rep will probably slip through.

Comment: attaching it to the badge ensures that they've figured out how to edit something.

Comment: Why not both? Or whichever one comes last? If they lose the "New Contributor" but still haven't earned "Editor", they keep getting the edit prompt until they earn "Editor". If they earn "Editor" but still have "New Contributor", they keep getting the edit prompt until they lose "New Contributor".

Comment: @HereticMonkey (and Robert) OK, I just went to read what the Editor badge is (been a long time since I earned it) and, sure, it could be done that way.

Comment: IIRC, if they try to comment, the UI already suggests they edit the question.